# Can I get ListConvolve to step by more than one element?

Tags: list-manipulation

This is probably a dumb question.

I found

```
res = ListConvolve[{1, 4, 1}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}]
```

gives

> ```
> {a + 4 b + c, b + 4 c + d, c + 4 d + e, d + 4 e + f, e + 4 f + g}
> ```

What if I want the result to be

> ```
> {a + 4 b + c, c + 4 d + e, e + 4 f + g}
> ```

I guess `ListConvolve` can generate this result directly instead of my having to evaluate `res[[1;;;;2]]`, but I can not figure it out by toying with `ListConvolve`'s additional arguments.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but a comment that is too long and messy to be a normal comment.

1. I can't see better way to do it than

   ```
   ListConvolve[{1, 4, 1}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}][[;; ;; 2]]
   ```

   Note that the initial 1 can be eliminated from `[[1;; ;; 2]]`
2. Another way to do it is to first partition the data and then map `ListConvolve` over it.

   ```
   p = Partition[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, 3, 2];
   ListConvolve[{1, 4, 1}, #] & /@ p
   ```

   However, I doubt this gives much if any advantage over using `Part`.
3. Since your kernel is symmetric, you could use `Dot` in place of `ListConvolve` on partitioned data.

   ```
   Dot[{1, 4, 1}, #] & /@ p
   ```

   That *might* give a slight advantage if the data list is long.

Comment: Thank you, m_goldberg. That makes me feel better. Because I am not so dumb after reading docs :)

Comment: An even better variation of point #3 is the following: `Partition[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, 3, 2].{1, 4, 1}` (c.c. @matheorem)

Comment: @J.M.'sennui, yeah, that's a lot better.